# Audio conference between two users - save stream

Tags: actionscript-3, red5

I created a script for a audio conference between two users. Now script works like:

1. Client X connect to red5 server, stream voice and play stream (voice) from Client Y.
2. Client Y connect to red5 server, stream voice and play stream (voice) from Client X.

I'm using publish method from AS3 with "live" argument and all works but now i want to record audio from their conference to a single file. I'm trying to create something like that:

1. Client X connect to red5 server, stream his voice with publish method and "live" argument. Additionally i recorded his voice with publish method and "append argument".  Of course as previously i play stream from Client Y.
2. Client Y have the same way.

All files was recorded properly but i want to record one file with voice from Client X and Y. Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

To get them into one file, you'll have to use a post processing tool. I believe there is such a feature in the BigBlueButton codebase for conference recordings.

https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton